# socket.io client with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I am trying to use TypeScript with socket.io in my client:

```
import { Manager, Socket} from "socket.io-client";
import {DefaultEventsMap} from "@socket.io/component-emitter";

export class SocketIoService {
    private socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>

    constructor() {
        const manager = new Manager("http://localhost:3000");
        this.socket = manager.socket("/");
    }

    public connect() {
        this.socket.emit("hello");
        this.socket.on("noArg", () => {
            // ...
        });

        this.socket.on("basicEmit", (a, b, c) => {
            // a is inferred as number, b as string and c as buffer
            console.log(a + b + c);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is when I start my server I get the following error:

```
The requested module './../../../parseuri/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown the code that attempts to import the default export from `'./../../../parseuri/index.js'`.

Comment: Are the compiler options `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` enabled?

Answer (score 3):

- Update the client-side
- Check updated documentation was updated here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#Syntax

Server:

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server(httpServer);
```

Client:

```js
import { Manager } from "socket.io-client";

const manager = new Manager("http://localhost:3000");
const socket = manager.socket("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

(this should have been a comment but I do not have enough rep to comment)

The error signifies that you are trying to `default import` from a module which has named exports.

Can you attach the stacktrace of the error?

I am interested in the module which triggers the import to './../../../parseuri/index.js'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how the error is related to this specific code. I just created an empty folder, added your code in, and with an empty `tsconfig.json` was able to compile. Here's the compiled code:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.SocketIoService = void 0;
var socket_io_client_1 = require("socket.io-client");
var SocketIoService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function SocketIoService() {
        var manager = new socket_io_client_1.Manager("http://localhost:3000");
        this.socket = manager.socket("/");
    }
    SocketIoService.prototype.connect = function () {
        this.socket.emit("hello");
        this.socket.on("noArg", function () {
            // ...
        });
        this.socket.on("basicEmit", function (a, b, c) {
            // a is inferred as number, b as string and c as buffer
            console.log(a + b + c);
        });
    };
    return SocketIoService;
}());
exports.SocketIoService = SocketIoService;
```

I'd suggest doing:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm i
```

And trying again.